how to make login page the main page the parent page using react?
I am trying to make a login page to my dashboard system, I created a component for that, but when I go to login page I can see Side bar, profile setting and something like that, I want to see login page first and when I login then I want to see dashboard, I don't know how pass this please help me!.
I tried to export it and import App.js but I seeing sidebar and profile settings.

You should provide at least some code to see the architecture of how you structured your app. But in the App.js or where you have your routes from react-router-dom just create another "/login" route to render that login component. If a user in NOT logged in and wants to see the dashboard render the login component, and if the user is logged in then render the dashboard component. That check you can perform again in the App.js where you render your dashboard component. <Route path="dashboard" element={loggedIn ?  : } /> assuming the login state is preserved
